# How to get the articles of shopmissa.com using CheerioJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cheerio

I'm trying to get all articles of this post. 
[This is my webiste so far](https://www.shopmissa.com/collections/eye-shadow).

But I am not good at using Cheerio, I only know how to get simple elements.
And, for example, the URL image of a product has a lot of children elements.

The data that I need, are:

- Article name,
- Price,
- URL,
- Image.

I started trying to get all the of the articles images with:

```
axios.get("https://www.shopmissa.com/collections/eye-shadow")
     .then(res => 
       { if(res.status == 200) 
         { const html = res.data; 
           const $ = cheerio.load(html); 
           $(".product-index").each((i, elem) => 
             { console.log($(this)
               .children(".prod-container")
               .children(".prod-image") 
               .find("a")
               .children("reveal")
               .find("img")
               .attr("src")
             ) 
           }
         ) 
       } 
     }, error => console.log(error)
   )
```

But I do not get the whole picture...
What can I do?

Comment: Please add what you've tried

Comment: Please edit the question to add your code. This way you're more likely to find someone to help you.

Comment: I edited your question to include the code of your comment. (From Review).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to focus on traversing each DOM, use the selectors to let cheerio do the heavy lifting.

```js
axios.get("https://www.shopmissa.com/collections/eye-shadow")
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status == 200) {
      const html = res.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      $("#product-loop").children().each((i, elem) => {
        var imageSource = $(elem).find(".reveal img").attr("src")
        var productName = $(elem).find(".product-info h3").text()
        var productPrice = $(elem).find(".product-info .money").text()
        console.log(imageSource, productName, productPrice)
      })
    }
  }, error => console.log(error))
```